# How to create footer links

Tags: 7, navigation

Does anyone know how to add link such as about us in the footer region. i am using the zen theme. Further, How do you redirect people to the login or register page from pages such as upload, thus if they are not logged in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You place your menu through the admin/structure/blocks form. Relocate the menu block from the disabled category at the bottom of the form to wherever you wish (footers).  To get rid of the name, select configure for the menu block and enter  in the Title box.

Comment: thanks again. Having done that how do i add links to the block? i've tried adding a link to my 'About Us' page through /admin/content but i can't find the block i've created.

Comment: This sounds like a new question, so go ahead and ask it.  People answer questions and gain reputation which entitles them to untold glory and fabulous prizes! :}

Comment: Go to the block, and manage it (edit the content). Damn I just missed a fabulous prizes! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can edit your footer in the "Manage block" section ("admin/structure/block").

Comment: thank you. i have tried but to no avail. i tried adding a new block but i couldn't add any links. i've also tried creating a new menu, which worked but i cannot remove the menu title. Any suggestions?

Comment: Go to the menus section and click on the menu you are trying to change click on list links and add link....

Answer (score 0):

Footer Map block is a good way. Its just a block of text links associated with certain menus... Or you could create a field view of the type of nodes or entitys you need and just create text links for the titles.